# jQuery ajax not remove spinner on success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

After successing ajax request and saving data in database i have problem when i try to remove `active` class from button. On click i show spinner and when ajax finish i want remove `active` class. On click spinner start but never stop. I try to debug it with `alert()`  inside `success` and i get message. WHat can be problem?

```
submiteComment: function() {

        $("body").on("click", '.submit-comment', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var post_id = $(this).data('post');
            var comment_text = $(".comment_text");

            if($.trim(comment_text).length) {

                $(this).addClass('active');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: baseurl + '/comment/create',
                    data: {'post': post_id, 'comment_text': comment_text.val()},
                    success: function() {
                         $(this).removeClass('active');
                         alert("Success");
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    },
```

**And html:**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-default submit-comment has-spinner" data-post="<?= $post->post_id;?>">
      <span class="spinner"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>
      Comment
</button>
```

Comment: I don't think it should work with $(this) in ajax call success part.

Comment: Could you give the button an ID and then try $("#id").removeClass("active"); ?

Comment: If u first read code and than commnet u will see `.submit-comment` class and also u will see ` $("body").on("click", '.submit-comment', function(e) `... So `this` is that button, like i say "Request is successfull executed"

Comment: which elemnt you have your class active ??

Comment: Can you try  $(".submit-comment").removeClass("active"); in success function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the `this` in  `$(this).removeClass('active');` is equal to your DOM element when your code is executed? Looks like you need rewrite part of your code as

```
success: (function() {
                     $(this).removeClass('active');
                     alert("Success");
                }).bind(this)
```

Comment: Yeah its work when i add `bind(this)`. Thanks @Vasyl

Answer (score 1):

you can assign $(this) as a var outside of ajax like

```
var $this = $(this);
 $this.addClass('active');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: baseurl + '/comment/create',
                    data: {'post': post_id, 'comment_text': comment_text.val()},
                    success: function() {
                         $this.removeClass('active');
                         alert("Success");
                    }
                })
```